# gstreamer get video playing event

Tags: gstreamer

I am quite new to gstreamer and trying to get some metrics on an existing pipeline. The pipeline is set as 'appsrc queue mpegvideoparse avdec_mpeg2video deinterlace videobalance xvimagesink'.

xvimagesink only has a sink pad and I am not sure where and how its output is connected to but I am interested in knowing when the actual video device/buffer displays the first I frame and then video starts rolling.

The application sets the pipeline state to 'playing' quite early on, so, listening on this event does not help.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [GST_MESSAGE_STREAM_START](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstMessage.html#GstMessageType) and [probes](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-dataaccess.html). However, I am not sure, what exactly do you want: at GStreamer level you can only detect moment when buffer is handled via some element, not when it's actually displayed.

[xvimagesink](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-xvimagesink.html#id-1.2.56.8.2.2) has no srcpad (output), only sinkpad (input).

You can read about preroll here: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/tree/docs/design/part-preroll.txt

Be sure to read GStreamer manual first:
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/index.html

Comment: I'll look into using probes more effectively but my problem is, the first I frame appears on the screen and then it takes around 2s to video start playing. I am trying to find out what is causing this delay and to be able to measure the affect of any changes, I'd like to get an event/print from the video decoder and base the call on that. I see the mention of ffmpeg video decoder in my gstreamer logs, do you know how I can get events like IFrame presented, video playing etc out of the player?

Comment: Let me recommend you my [GStreamer profiler](https://github.com/kirushyk/gst-instruments), you can find out what element eats your time.

Comment: It looks useful and I'll try it. However, after your probe suggestion, now I can monitor the data flow in the pipeline but it all disappears when the data enters the xvimagesink element. I want to get some metrics from the video decoder (ffmpeg) too. Because, the mpeg-2 ts is fed to appsrc from a file by our app and then there is our plugin between the appsrc and queue which does soft demuxing. So, I want to make sure data we pace the data efficiently for the viddec.The events that I am particularly interested in are first I-Frame displayed and video playing/stopped/paused transitions.